# Motion a ball thrown from a non-accelerated body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

When a ball is thrown vertically with only a vertical component in an accelerating vehicle, the motion of the ball is **parabolic** and the ball moves backward relative to the body. What is the motion of the ball when it is thrown up only with a vertical velocity, in a **non-accelerated body**?

Comment: Think about what make the ball follow a parabolic trajectory.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't seem to reach an answer. Could you please  elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the motion of the ball when it is thrown up only with a
>   vertical velocity, in a non-accelerated body?

The trajectory of the ball will still be parabolic.

This is because it will have a constant horizontal speed and a constant vertical acceleration. A constant horizontal speed means that the horizontal coordinate will be a linear function of time: $x=v_{x0}t$, while a constant vertical acceleration means that the vertical coordinate will be a quadratic function of time: $y=v_{y0}t-\frac {gt^2} 2$.

Based on this, we could conclude that the $y(x)$ should be a quadratic function of $x$. We could also show it by replacing $t$ in the equation of $y$ by $\frac x {v_{x0}}$:

$y(x)=v_{y0}\frac x {v_{x0}}-\frac g 2 \frac {x^2} {v_{x0}^2}=ax^2+bx$

which is a general equation for a parabola.

The difference from the first scenario is that the ball won't move backwards relative to the body, because, if we ignore air resistance, the horizontal velocity of the ball will be the same as the horizontal velocity of the body.

Comment: So when you are in the vehicle how do you differentiate it from accelerated or non-accelerared?

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I'll start a new string as this question is totally different...

Comment: @Mundaplackal If the vehicle is accelerating and you throw the ball up, the ball will fall behind. If the the vehicle is not accelerating, the ball will just go up and then come back into you hands, as if the vehicle did not move at all.